# How to Integrate moodle with asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, integration, moodle

I want to integrate moodle with my asp.net site. Is there any way to follow so that We can access moodle feature on my dot net site? Also can moodle work with sql server database?

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can integrate moodle with .net application using webservices.
because moodle expose the same methods using several protocols that can be accessed by .net or any application.

here is a useful link if that helps: 
https://delog.wordpress.com/2010/09/08/integrating-c-app-with-moodle-2/

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation Moodle is written in PHP, so no you will not be able to easily integrate it into your .Net site. However, there is no reason why you couldn't host the Moodle application as a virtual directory/application/sub-domain as IIS will allow you to host PHP applications.

Also, yes you can use MS SQL Server with Moodle.

A good [overview of Moodle can be found here](http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Moodle_architecture).